# Fixed header only in parent

Tags: header, position, z-index, fixed

Well my code looks like this:

```
<header>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixedHeader">
        <span>some stuff here like logo and nav element</span>
    </div>
    <span>another header stuff here</span>
</div>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span>sections stuff here</span>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span>sections stuff here</span>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span>footer stuff here</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

the `<header></header>`is 100vh
when I scroll down the `div.fixedHeader` that is positioned `fixed` is visible only in the `<header>` area but it disappears in sections and footer
how can i fix it? i tried the `z-index` but it's pointless